# How to shield comma in Managed Metadata Service import file?

Tags: taxonomy

I have a few files (*.csv) with random taxonomy structure.
Many of this contains commas, which are interpreted during import as next level terms.
Now i'm using spaces instead of commas to evade this.

But maybe this is another method to preserve commas in terms structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, values in CSV files that include commas are wrapped in double quotes, i.e. `"Value1,Value2,Value3"`.